# Tkinter insert text on last line of text widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a text widget height=12 width=50 and I want add a line of text on the last line, ie like a footer.
The rest of the text widget could have a different number of lines.
I thought I could use "displaylines" which I thought gave total number of lines available, and tkDocs states to use "1.0+2 displaylines" to insert on a given line but it does not work, line appears after last line inserted.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
T = Text(root, bg='blue', height=12, width=50)#height/width blue background
T.config(foreground='yellow', padx=40, pady=40, font=('Times New Roman', 36, "bold"))    
T.pack()
T.insert("1.0", song_file_vpclli + '\n' + 'Welcome to VizPraise song display\n')   
T.insert("1.0+9 displaylines", no_usb)
```

Using this to get number of lines it only gives lines already inserted and not the number of display lines available.

```
count=T.count("1.0", END, "displaylines")[0]
```

How can I add a last line?

Comment: Will `.insert(END, ...` not work ?

Comment: I think the `"displaylines"` counting value argument used with the `Text.count()` method is **broken** (I'm using Python 3.8.1) because it's giving me the of value of the number of _characters_ displayed in the widget (which doesn't include the newline characters).

Comment: P.S. If I use `count = T.count("1.0", END, "lines")[0]` it returns the value `3` which seems correct.

Comment: @martineau: I highly doubt displaylines is broken. That's been a part of tk and tkinter for a least a decade, maybe two. Somebody would have noticed by now.

Comment: Are you wanting this footer as the last line of text, or literally at the bottom of the widget with a bunch of blank space between the last line and this footer?

Comment: @Bryan: Try it and see.

Comment: @martineau: the problem is that the text widget hasn't been displayed yet, so the concept of displayed lines is somewhat undefined. Until it's been displayed, the widget is only one character wide, and with the default wrapping on characters, each character will be on a different displayed line. Thus, the number of displaylines equals the number of characters.

Comment: @Bryan: As usual, you're right. `"displaylines"` also gives `3` if I add a `Button` to call `count()` and click that after the text is displayed.

Comment: "or literally at the bottom of the widget with a bunch of blank space between the last line and this footer"  Yes..

Comment: Have used a GPIO button after screen has displayed showing the 3 lines and blank lines, still gives 3.

Comment: The 3rd line is the line I want at the bottom,  "1.0+9 displaylines" does not work.

Comment: The `1.0+9` is interpreted as the position following the first nine (`0+9`) _characters_ at the beginning of the first line. If you want to move `N` lines past the beginning, use `1.0+N lines`.

Comment: The 1.0+N lines does not work, it still puts it at the 3rd line.  tkDocs states to use "1.0+2 displaylines"

Comment: •When moving up or down a certain number of lines, this is interpreted as logical lines, where each line is terminated only by the "\n". With long lines and wrapping enabled, this may be represent multiple lines on the display. If you'd like to move up or down a single line on the display, you can specify this as e.g. "1.0 + 2 display lines".